# Magento 2 : window.checkoutConfig returns empty, So Checkout page is not loaded without configuration values

Tags: checkout, magento2.3.1, system-config, core-config-data

Here My Checkout page is not loading which throws following issue

[image]

It also shows like below while hit checkout page.

[image] 
Can anyone please suggest me the solution for this.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you found solution to this?

Answer (score 1):

I have the same issue and after a little debugging i found out following

- In my case it's a encoding problem
- mb_detect_encoding returns probably a faulty response, some strings were probably not UTF-8
- using utf8_encode() on those string solved my problem, but see note below

Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19366999/5668224

Comment: Hey! thanks for your solution. It works for me, but I don't understand how magento has this issue in its core files. Is it because of some external configuration? I checked my mysql database charset and it is utf8. Thanks for the help.